# Linkedin oauth2 get user profile from access token

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I am getting error of Unknown authentication scheme. My request url is 
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?header=Authorization%3A+Bearer+MY ACCESS TOKEN%0D%0Ax-li-format%3A+json%0D%0A

Please tell me where I am wrong. My scope is same in files and dev account

Comment: Could you show your code? It looks like your headers are ending up as query parameters in the URL, which is not quite right.

Comment: Hi, I have done it by myself. Can you help me in one way?As rw_groups scope has been restricted from may 12,2015. I will have to create Partner program and that is a lengthy process of 15 days. I am working on some project on local. I want to test using my test app. How I can use rw_groups scope easily?Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The header value with your `Authorization + bearer token` is not meant to be passed as a URL parameter, it's meant to be included as an actual HTTP header in your request.

Same goes for the `x-li-format`.